# preg_replace and json_decode - Ajax handler - php

Tags: php, arrays, ajax

I have problem with array in `PHP`.
I've got that code in my Ajax handler `PHP` page:

```
if(isset($_GET['dataa']))
{
$dataa = $_GET['dataa'];
$dataa = preg_replace('/\\\"(.*?)\\\"/', '"$1"', $dataa);
$dataa = json_decode($dataa);
echo $dataa[0];
echo $dataa[1];
}
```

I tried to send data array in `JavaScript` to the Ajax handler but it's not working so I want to to pass param in the URL.

When I try to put this URL:
`...AjaxHandler.php?dataa=["test1","test2"]`
I get this: `test1test2` and that's ok.

But I don't really understand why I need to use `preg_replace` and `json_decode`.
I tried to delete the `preg_replace` but then it didn't show me anything.
I tried to delete the `json_decode` too but then I get only `[/` on the screen.

I need to send multiple data so I do that with array.

Why I have to use `preg_replace`?
Is it common to use `preg_replace` like that? All time when I send data array?

Comment: The `json_decode($dataa)` is producing either `NULL` because it can't decode it or and object because you haven't set the array flag. Try `json_decode($dataa, true)` and see if it fixes it.

Comment: i tryed json_decode($dataa, true) like you write but its not work to..
what sould i put in the url?

Comment: Can you provide sample data that you're getting. Since you're sending JSON data through $_GET it might be getting mangled by URL encoding, that's where $_POST is better. Testing your input you stated and your code, I don't need the preg_replace.